# Bootstrap:Fixed nav-static-top on top but scrollable nav-collapse

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to design my site.

Base on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Snippet/Vy2Em/1/)

I made the `nav-static-top` to fixed on top. Now the `nav-collapse` has to many contents and i can't browse to the last menu because the `nav-static-top` is fixed on top. Is there a way that the 
`nav-static-top` is fixed on top and the `nav-collapse` content is scrollable so i can scroll to choose on the content?

i've than something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Snippet/Vy2Em/6/) but i doesn't look good
and i think android devices don't support  `overflow:scroll`

Answer (score 2):

Found a better way. Tested on iphone 4 only.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
.body-container {
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px; 
}

.navbar-static-top{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}
.navbar-responsive-collapse{
    max-height: 350px;  
        overflow-y: auto; 
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't completely fix your problem, but it definitely looks better if you do this:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" style="overflow-y: scroll;max-height:400px">
<ul class="nav">
```

instead of

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
<ul class="nav" style="overflow: scroll;max-height:400px">
```

I don't know about doing it on Android, but if it really doesn't work this way, you'll probably have write some JS or something.